# Verifying if a user actually owns the address

Tags: web3js, nethereum

Web3js frontend with Vue, .NET Core with Nethereum at the back.

> The key target for this functionality is to sign a message at the frontend, send the signature and the address to the backend to validate that he actually owns that address.
>
> **The problem is that I keep ending up with varying address results. This definitely means that some part of my code is wrong. Anyone can spot the problem? <3**

***For the purpose of development testing, I've added the raw message as part of the API for now.***

1. Frontend

   ```
                 // Modern dapp browsers...
                 if (window.ethereum) {
                     // Propagate Web3
                     window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
                     await window.ethereum.enable();
                     window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;

                     // Obtain the user accounts
                     let authMsg = 'This is a Nozomi auth message';
                     let accounts = await window.web3.eth.getAccounts();

                     // Ensure that the user is holding the wallet/s by asking him to unlock his
                     // account with a random message.
                     // https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48489/how-to-prove-that-a-user-owns-their-public-key-for-free=
                     if (accounts != null && accounts.length > 0) {
                         // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop
                         // await Promise.all(accounts.map(async (account) => {
                         // }));

                         let shaMsg = window.web3.utils.sha3(authMsg);
                         let signed = await window.web3.eth.accounts.sign(accounts[0], shaMsg,
                             function (err, sig) {
                                 console.dir("Signature: " + sig);
                                 this.$buefy.notification.open({
                                     duration: 5000,
                                     message: `There was an error signing the validation request.`,
                                     position: 'is-bottom-right',
                                     type: 'is-danger',
                                     hasIcon: true
                                 });
                             });

                         console.dir("User signed data: ");
                         console.dir(signed);

                         // Validate the signed object on server side and provide an auth
                         let result = await axios({
                             method: 'post',
                             headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                             url: '/api/auth/ethauth',
                             data: {
                                 "claimerAddress": accounts[0],
                                 "signature": signed.signature,
                                 "rawMessage": authMsg
                             }
                         }).then(function (response) {
                             console.log(response);
                         }).catch(function (error) {
                             console.log(error);
                         });

                         console.dir("result: " + result);
                     }
                 }
   ```
2. Backend

   ```
       public bool ValidateOwner(ValidateOwnerQuery request)
       {
           // Null Checks
           var addrValidator = new AddressUtil();
           if (request == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.RawMessage) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Signature) 
               || addrValidator.IsAnEmptyAddress(request.ClaimerAddress)
               || !addrValidator.IsValidEthereumAddressHexFormat(request.ClaimerAddress))
               return false;

           // Check for validity
           var signer = new EthereumMessageSigner();

           var resultantAddr = signer.EncodeUTF8AndEcRecover(request.RawMessage, request.Signature);
           return !addrValidator.IsAnEmptyAddress(resultantAddr) && resultantAddr.Equals(request.ClaimerAddress);
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the web3.eth.accounts API, use web3.eth.personal to sign the message since you're using the user's address to sign the message, not his/her private key.

[MetaMask verification on a server with web3.personal.sign](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54715/metamask-verification-on-a-server-with-web3-personal-sign)

Instead of

```
let signed = await window.web3.eth.accounts.sign(accounts[0], shaMsg,
                          function (err, sig) {
                              console.dir("Signature: " + sig);
                          });
```

Do

```
let signed = await window.web3.eth.personal.sign(authMsg, accounts[0],
                              function (err, sig) {
                                  console.dir("Signature: " + sig);
                              });
```