# How can I securely verify a user owns an address from Metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have a website where I want to verify a user owns an address. There will be no purchases on this site. I just need to drop the address into a file and know the user owns it. I looked at [How to verify MetaMask account holder is the real owner of the address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/how-to-verify-metamask-account-holder-is-the-real-owner-of-the-address), amongst other similar articles. They all rely on the JS API. A malicious user can overwrite `ethereum` or `web3` in the browser to trigger my callbacks that are listening to what I'd expect from MetaMask. Then I'd say they own this address. I took a look [Verifying if a user actually owns the address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74759/verifying-if-a-user-actually-owns-the-address) which made me realize there may be a backend way to solve this, but I don't use .NET.

Is there a way to use metamask in conjunction with a backend that can verify the user owns the address? Is Nethereum the standard answer and/or is there a similar library for Nodejs or any other languages? I saw https://www.npmjs.com/package/nethereum-codegen, but honestly don't understand what I am looking at.

Comment: the only way to  know if the user owns an account is to ask for a signature on a message (any message, not necesarily a tx) , so you will have to force user to pop up a window and sign it

Comment: @Nulik but is there a writeup / good article somewhere about how to get that sign to a server to validate? Only being in browser isn't good validation.

Comment: Basically where do I go with this signed info to check against and decrypt properly

Comment: The first linked question solves the problem from the Ethereum side, the way to validate an address is with a signed message, you can do the validation on the server side.

Comment: I totally did not read with my eyes yesterday. Sorry about that. You are right @Ismael.